# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText Со всеми нужными gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

при добавлении TextInputLayout в приложении оно не загружается и вывод в log данную ошибку. В чем может быть причина?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".First_Layout.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout


        android:id="@+id/translate"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
            android:id="@+id/wordEnglishMainActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/app_name">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Find"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Find"
            android:onClick="Find"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/Recycler"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>





    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Вот сам Gradle

```
compile group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha05'


    compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'design', version: '28.0.0'

    compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'appcompat-v7', version: '28.0.0'
```

Comment: у вас в res/values/style.xml  прописан сам стиль Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox ?

Comment: Нет. Похоже в этом и причина. Спасибо